# How to ensure there are no run time errors in python

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I am quite new to python programming and working on a quite large python module using IntelliJ. I was wondering if I have a static method that is called from multiple places and I change the signature of this method to accept a different no. of arguments. I might fix the actual method calls in some places but might miss changing the calls in some other. In java, I will receive a compile time error but since python is interpreted I will only figure out that sometime during runtime(probably in production). Till now I have been using the command 'python -m compileall' but I was wondering like in Java is there any way to get syntax errors in IntelliJ.

Comment: unit tests were created for a reason

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson Agree, and so were good programmer's editors.  If your function is well named it should be possible to find and check all calls pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests and static code analysis tools such as [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) will help. `pylint` is able to detect incorrect number of arguments being passed to functions.

If you're using Python 3, function annotations might be useful, and [`mypy`](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) can type check annotated function calls (apparently, I've not used it).

In general the strategy for changing existing function signatures without breaking dependent code is to use keyword arguments. For example, if you wanted to add a new argument to a function, add it as a keyword argument:

```
#def f(a):
#    """Original function"""
#    print(a)

def f(a, b=None):
    """New and improved function"""
    print(a)
    if b is not None:
        print(b)
```

Now calls with and without the new argument will work:

```
>>> f('blah')
blah
>>> f('blah', 'cough')
blah
cough
```

Of course this will not always work, e.g. if argument(s) are removed, or if the semantics of the function are changed in a way that breaks existing code.